# Spawned object always null

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am using Unity 2017. Executing the code below on the host side works fine `(mCume != null)`, however, on the client side it always ends with `mCume == null`.

Am I missing something?

```
public GameObject cubePrefab;    
public GameObject mCume;

void Update()
{
    if (isLocalPlayer)
    {  
        CmdSpawnCube();
    }
}
[Command]
void CmdSpawnCube()
{
    mCume = (GameObject)Instantiate(cubePrefab);
    NetworkServer.Spawn(mCume);
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Try sending cubePrefab to NetworkServer.Spawn() instead of mCume

Comment: The mCume object is being spawned perfectly by the NetworkServer. I need the mCume object to perform some manipulations on it.

Comment: I suppose that you are using UNet. To manipulate objects I recall I found the corresponding object on all clients through the network identity first. Then I did the manipulating.

Comment: @Asbest The mCume GameObject has both the NetworkIdentity and the NetworkTransform components. Still is doesn't work. Currently i am passing object's NetworkInstanceIds between client and server, but i am still curious what went wrong in the example i posted above. As far as i understand it should work.